# Mathematical ideas named after places

Tags: notation, sociology-of-math, big-list

This question is quite unimportant, so feel free to close if you think it is inappropriate.

I've been thinking about how mathematicians come up with names for the ideas/objects they study, and how that differs from the practices of people in other fields.

It seems that almost always we do one of two things: 1) we pick a name that describes some feature of the object (sometimes not very well, e.g. flat modules, sets of second category), or 2) we name it after a person (who may or may not have studied that object).

Very rarely we name something after a place. (This is much more common in other fields.)
I can think of only 3 examples:

*Japanese rings

*Polish spaces

*Tropical geometry

Does anyone know of any other examples in mathematics?

Comment: Yet another empty question...

Comment: http://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/2010/08/19/what-countries-are-mathematical-objects/

Comment: +1, I think this is at least a little amusing.  I must admit, I don't understand why this question has been received poorly (as indicated by the number of votes on SNd's comment, and the number of upvotes on the question itself) when other "empty questions," such as the one about jokes, get over 30 positive votes.  What am I missing?

Comment: A matter of timing, I suspect. The crowd is just not in the mood.

Comment: @Eric: What you're missing is that voting here is subjective and there are a lot of hotheads here.  (Harry Gindi has admitted that when he was a newbie here, he was in the habit of expressing many negative votes in cases where he could not have explained why he did so.  There's a lot of evidence that things like that still happen frequently.)

Comment: -1. I voted this down because I don't see the value in the question being open (just go to Emmanuel's blog post if you're interested in this). The question is just taking up valuable real estate on the front page as it gets continually bumped by what are generally low quality answers. (and even the OP claims the question is unimportant!)

Comment: @Peter I agree that the quality of answers has declined significantly and I am voting to close. Still I don't think that in itself justifies down-voting.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: In chess many openings were named after countries (e.g. the English, Dutch, French, Spanish, Russian) or after cities or regions (e.g. the Sicilian, the Scheveningen variation, the Leningrad variation). In recent times openings are more often named after their inventors to give them credit, like with mathematical ideas and theorems. So I guess to find mathematical ideas named after places you also have to dig deep in history and look for ancient results, such as the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: I reluctantly voted down because I just don't think it's right for such a question to almost monopolize the top of the list for 2 days.

Comment: I've given the last vote to close.  My reasons are roughly the same as those above: I'll just note that when the OP of a big-list thread votes to close it, that probably means its time to stick a fork in it.

Comment: Since it's now closed, I de-down-voted.

Comment: For me, references to "valuable space on the front page" and "top of the list" sound like nonsense.
 

Comment: "List of mathematical concepts named after places" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_concepts_named_after_places) is a new Wikipedia article, based initiallly on answers to this question in this forum, and later contribued to by various people. It was moved into the article space (thereby becoming a Wikiepdia article) on November 26th, after being in the user space for a few months.

Answer (score 32):

universal example?

Answer (score 31):

[Loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loop) (aka quasigroups with identity):

> It was at this point that the terminology of quasigroup theory underwent a
>   historic change. It became apparent that it was necessary to distinguish between
>   two classes of quasigroups: those with and those without an identity element.
>   A new name was needed to designate the system with identity. This occurred
>   around 1942, among people of Albert’s circle in Chicago, who coined the word
>   “loop” after the Chicago Loop. For Chicago locals, the term “Loop” designated
>   the main business area and the elevated train that literally made a loop around
>   this part of the city.

(taken from [Historical notes on loop theory](http://www.emis.de/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc0002/pflug.pdf), by Hala Orlik Pflugfelder)

Comment: Ah! Now this is a piece of knowledge I've been (not very actively...) looking for years :)

Answer (score 22):

The French Railroad metric: if $(X,d)$ is a metric space, and $p \in X$, define $d_R(x,y) = 0$ if $x = y$ and $d_R(x,y) = d(x,p) + d(y,p)$ otherwise. Apparently named so because almost every train in France goes trough Paris.

Comment: also called "la distance SNCF"

Comment: also called the "Washington DC metric"


Comment: and the "British Rail metric"

Comment: +1 for the comments especially.

Comment: Why is this the Washington DC metric? (Washington is not nearly as central in the US as London is in the UK or Paris is in France...)

Comment: I've heard this called the Roman Road metric, as in "all roads lead to Rome."

Comment: In Cambridge (US) it might be reasonable to call this the "Harvard Square metric".

Comment: @Michael Probably because of the layout of the DC Metro--to move between two outer locations (say Shady Grove and Vienna/Fairfax), one often has to travel to the center of the District along the way.

Comment: Yes, it refers to the DC street layout.  All streets radiating out from the Capitol in the center.


Answer (score 18):

Königsberg bridge problem

Answer (score 18):

The Hawaiian earring:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring

The space H is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of the union of a countably infinite family of open intervals.

Answer (score 13):

[Topos](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/topos) (sorry!)

Comment: Don't apologize: this is an excellent answer!

Comment: then also "geometry"

Answer (score 12):

[Japanese theorem for cyclic polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_theorem_for_cyclic_polygons)

[Monte Carlo method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)

[Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

Answer (score 11):

[Toronto space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_space).

Answer (score 10):

anarboricity of graphs (named in honor of the city of Ann Arbor by Frank Harary, but also having something to do with non-trees (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Anarboricity.html)

Comment: This mixes a Greek prefix with a Latin word, and is therefore an abomination (like "television" and "automobile").

Comment: Yes, the horrors. Children, cover your ears. 

Comment: I agree with Todd, especially if the children also stay away from the television.

Answer (score 9):

Manhattan distance

Chinese restaurant process

Comment: Is the Chinese restaurant process named after the place "China", or the place "Chinese restaurant"?

Comment: It's named after the custom of table-sharing in Chinese restaurants, which in turn are named after the place.

Comment: Yes, interestingly there is also a variation called the 'Indian buffet process'

Comment: I don't really like Indian food, so I never understood why the Indian buffet process is so-called.

Comment: The CRP is named after a particular restaurant in Berkeley.

Answer (score 9):

The Chinese remainder theorem.

The Mexican hat wavelet.

Arabic (or Roman) numerals.

Answer (score 9):

The [Erlangen program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program).

Answer (score 8):

[Italian squares](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ey8iXKkQpDkC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=%22italian+square%22+latin+tuscan&source=bl&ots=AzcDDPTqUk&sig=v9GIP3l1wKs6Yu0oXXnLQfxbJlQ&hl=en&ei=7u3KTd6uNoragQeLr5HeBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22italian%20square%22%20latin%20tuscan&f=false) which include Latin squares, Tuscan squares, Roman squares, Florentine squares and Vatican squares as special cases.

Comment: And there is the Syracusan Square which is a special case of Graeco-Latin square ...

Answer (score 7):

Nottingham group

Answer (score 7):

"The Roman surface (so called because Jakob Steiner was in Rome when he thought of it) is a self-intersecting mapping of the real projective plane into three-dimensional space, with an unusually high degree of symmetry."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_surface

Answer (score 6):

(Non-Serious)
Well, depending on how far you wish to stretch the term "place"

[Midpoint Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method)

Comment: More non-serious (read: "wrong") answers: Hessian matrix
(Stone-)Czech compactification, Wiener process.


Comment: Another non-serious answer: I was born in an Australian town called *Singleton*; the population of Singleton is larger than $1$, so it is a rather misleading name.

Answer (score 6):

The Scottish Book, named as you know for the [Scottish Cafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Caf%25C3%25A9) in Lwow where Banach and his friends would meet and discuss mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

Aarhus integral, Polish notation, English/French notation (or something like that - it refers to different ways to draw Ferrers diagrams - or was it English/Italian?), Tower of Hanoi, Russian constructivism (Russian school of intuitionism).

Comment: There's also a "Russian notation" for Ferrers diagrams, although I can't remember what it is.

Answer (score 5):

[Las Vegas algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm).

Comment: Also: Monte Carlo algorithms and Atlantic City algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

There is Colmez's "Montréal functor" which is part of the $p$-adic local Langlands business. The story is he introduced it in a lecture in Montréal.

Comment: Dear Rob, I'm glad you mentioned this; it was the first example that came to my mind!  And yes, he introduced it in a fantastic lecture in Montreal.  Best wishes, Matt

Answer (score 5):

The [Woods Hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah-Bott_fixed-point_theorem#History) formula, as that is where there was a race to prove this Riemann-Roch-Lefschetz formula.

Answer (score 5):

Two more are:

Egyptian fractions

Canadian Traveler Problem

Answer (score 5):

Nowhere differentiable: named for Ainsworth, Nebraska, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a stretch, but in mathematical finance it is traditional to name option styles after places.  American and European are the most common, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_style also lists Bermudan, Canary, Asian, Russian, Israeli, and Parisian.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Four Russians algorithm in computer science.  I don't remember what the algorithm did or who the four Russians were, but the description "named after the cardinality and nationality of its inventors" stuck in my mind.  I think that description is from the first edition of Principles of Compiler Design (aka the Green Dragon Book) by Aho and Ullman.  (Googling finds some descriptions of the algorithm).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the four Russians were V.L. Arlazarov, E.A. Dinic, M.A. Kronrod and I.A. Faradjev, authors of the paper

On economical finding of transitive closure of a graph. Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 194 (1970).

Answer (score 4):

The [Delian problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube).

Answer (score 3):

Dubrovnik polynomial

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: A knot polynomial defined by Kaufman using skein relations while at a conference in Dubrovnik (or so I understand). 

Comment: What if the conference had been in Split? 

Answer (score 3):

The Cracovian algebra- of matrices with some non-associative multiplication

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracovian

Answer (score 2):

The [Conway-Paterson-Moscow theorem](http://www.tanyakhovanova.com/BlogStuff/Conway/Headache.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

While visiting the city in question, Nesetril defined an ultrafilter he called a Riga P-point.

Answer (score 2):

Two amusing examples from distributed computing are:

The [Bysentian generals problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance).  The problem asks for an algorithm that allows a large number of processors to reach a consensus on something (say a bit value) when some of the processors behave in a malicious way. The original paper motivated the problem with a fictional account of Byzantine generals trying to coordinate a joint attack. There's also a related "Chinese Generals Problem".

[Paxos algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29). This is a family of algorithms that also allow a number of participants to reach a consensus. These were introduced by Leslie Lamport in paper written as a story about the downfall of an ancient Parliament on the (fictional) island of Paxos. The story ends when the parliament inadvertently restricts membership to dead sailors which, of course, can then not be corrected. As you can read about [here](http://research.microsoft.com/users/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#lamport-paxos), the novel exposition of the paper led to a very delayed publication of what has since been recognized as an important result (and is [reportedly used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29#Production_use_of_Paxos) in Google, Microsoft and IBM products).

Answer (score 2):

The [Warsaw circle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Warsaw+circle) is a motivating example in shape theory.

Answer (score 1):

The Aarhus integral of rational homology 3-spheres
http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9706004

Answer (score 1):

Swiss cheese (one type in complex analysis, another in cosmology)

Comment: Don't forget the Swiss cheese operad. 

Answer (score 1):

[The Oberwolfach Problem and the Hamilton-Waterloo Problem](http://www.spsu.edu/math/holliday/Oberwolfachs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/2010/08/19/what-countries-are-mathematical-objects/

Answer (score 1):

K. Barré-Sirieix, G. Diaz, F. Gramain and G. Philibert proved the Mahler–Manin conjecture in St-Étienne, so the result is now called the "Theorem of St-Étienne" (see Hida's book *Hilbert modular forms and Iwasawa theory*, p. 62). The theorem states that the Tate parameter of an elliptic curve $E_{/\overline{\mathbf{Q}}}$ with split, multiplicative reduction is transcendental (over $\mathbf{Q}$).

Answer (score 1):

The semi-symmetric [Ljubljana graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljubljana_graph), from algebraic graph theory.

Answer (score 1):

Black Cow Factor in *Optimal Cloning of Pure States* by R.F. Werner (arXiv:quant-ph/9804001). He writes,

"The reason for this terminology is that it plays an important role in discussions of the
cloning problem started by Chiara Machiavello and Artur Ekert at the Black Cow Café in
Croton-on-Hudson, NY, and further clarified in collaboration with Dagmar Bruß [BEM].
I learned about this line of argument from a set of “Black Cow Notes” by Nicolas Gisin
and Sandu Popescu."

Answer (score 1):

The Arctic Circle Theorem (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801068)

Answer (score 1):

[outer space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out%28Fn%29)

Answer (score 0):

In computer science, the Vienna Definition Language, or the related Vienna Development Method.  (A tool for definining program semantics).

Answer (score -1):

Italian Algebraic Algebraic Geometry

One that is not but I used to think so: Catalan number :)

Answer (score -3):

What if named after a person who derives his name from a place?

e.g. Hamburger expansion

How about moonshine? If moon is allowed, why not Stone (as in Stone-Weierstrass)? And then Stein manifold, Einstein metric, Eisenstein criterion?

There are also buildings and chambers and apartments of Jacques Tits.
(BTW, is the last word of previous sentence a place?)

Comment: Why focus on Stone? Surely Weierstrass got his name from the Weierstrasse, on which one of his ancestors happened to live. But I am afraid this new twist opens up a potential avalanche of responses, and I would rather discourage pursuing it.